# UWP- Version 1809, Connected/Coordinated Animations not configured the same

Tags: c#, .net, uwp

**The goal:**
I'm working on a UWP app that was created prior to Version 1809. We used connected animations to animate a button clicked on from page 1 to the header of page 2 during navigation. Page 2 has text that follows the animated button as if it is pinned underneath it during navigation (Coordinated Animation). Everything worked and looked nice. This is what we need to get back to.

**The problem:** We want to update the framework to utilize the new features in version 1809. But the framework contains updates to the connected animations and coordinated animations that change their functionality. By default there is a new "Gravity animation" that the connected animations follow. The button dips down and pops into place at the last minute instead of moving straight into place as before.

You can read about the changes here:
[MS DOCS: Connected animation for UWP apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/motion/connected-animation)

The above documentation recommended changing the configuration to use the BasicConnectedAnimationConfiguration. We did this and it helped a little. The button now animates in a straight line like before. Nice.

**Unfortunately the coordinated components still use the "Gravity" configuration.** They drop down and pop into place, not being pinned to the animating button/header. Also, they have a drop shadow during animation that looks pretty bad as it creates depth between the coordinated components that should look like they are all on the same z plane.

**The question I have here is**: How do I make the coordinated elements in the animation use the BasicConnectedAnimationConfiguration instead of the new Default GravityConnectedAnimationConfiguration?
The documentation shows how to override the connected animation but not the coordinated.

Here is how I am implementing it:

Page1.cs:

```
 protected override void OnNavigatingFrom(NavigatingCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            ConnectedAnimationService.GetForCurrentView()?
                .PrepareToAnimate("ThumbnailToHeaderAnimation", _Button);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

Page2.cs:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
        _animation = ConnectedAnimationService.GetForCurrentView().GetAnimation("ThumbnailToHeaderAnimation");
        _animation.Configuration = new BasicConnectedAnimationConfiguration();
        if (_animation != null)
        {
            _animation.Completed += Animation_Completed;
            isAnimating = _animation.TryStart(HeaderImage, new UIElement[] { HeaderTitleCard, HeaderDescriptionCard });
        }
```

Edit: A video of the issue can be found here:
https://1drv.ms/v/s!Arqp85_Yjalzj554Bm39QAF6y_LkUw

A link to a sample project I created to demonstrate the issue:
https://github.com/BrandonKuenzi/CoordinatedAnimationIssue

Comment: When I used your code in version 1903 to play the coordinated animation and it worked well. It animates in a straight line after adding the BasicConnectedAnimationConfiguration in the animation. So is your coordinated animation still drop down and then pop into the place by adding the BasicConnectedAnimationConfiguration? Can you provide a simple sample that can be reproduced for us to test?

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. I just now created a new project targeting 1903. I made it as simple as possible and found the issue is still there. If you want to see a video of the issue I made a screen recording: https://1drv.ms/v/s!Arqp85_Yjalzj554Bm39QAF6y_LkUw The problem is subtle in this demo but in our more complex app it is a big problem. For your own testing, if page 1's button is positioned to the side of where page 2's header will be then the problem is more noticeable.

Comment: I also uploaded this new demo of the issue to GitHub: https://github.com/BrandonKuenzi/CoordinatedAnimationIssue

Comment: You mentioned "We want to update the framework to utilize the new features in version 1809", what framework did you refer to?

Comment: Sorry that wasn't clear. @Faywang-MSFT I simply meant the targeted version of UWP. We want to be able to target 1809 or 1903. But starting in 1809 coordinated animations behave differently. The official documentation, linked above: _"Starting in Windows 10, version 1809, connected animations further embody Fluent design by providing animation configurations tailored specifically for forward and backwards page navigation."_

Comment: Thanks for your reporting this issue, I can reproduce this issue. We are still investigating this issue, I will let you know the update as soon as possible.

Comment: Thanks @Faywang-MSFT, Ill be checking back.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is a limitation of coordinated animations at this time. We're tracking the fix for this bug on the main WinUI repo: https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/2035

In the meantime, consider swapping the coordinated animation with a connected animation that has the configuration set, and connect between the Text and an empty grid instead.